# What is the difference between the examples: div.panel.panel-default and .panel.panel-default?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm fairly new to programming and jQuery in general. I've taken a few programming courses in college and have been learning more and more of the respective subjects during my free time. I've tried doing some research on this subject as I generally do with these interesting coding functions that I'm not aware of. However, Google and elsewhere has surprisingly not been very helpful on this subject.

What is the difference between the following examples for jQuery selectors?

`div.panel.panel-default` vs `.panel.panel-default`

I'm fairly familiar with using selectors in the example .panel.panel-default for my jQuery scripts but this is the first time I've seen `div.panel.panel-default`. I've seen this code being used in this example:

```
$( 'div.panel.panel-default' ).hide();
$( 'div.panel.panel-default:first' ).show();
```

Comment: The first selector requires that the selected item is a `div`. The second doesn't.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first selector requires you that the element is a `div`, the second one can be any element.

`$('div.panel.panel-default')` selects only: `<div class="panel panel-default">`

`$('.panel.panel-default')` selects for example:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<p class="panel panel-default">
<span class="panel panel-default">
<header class="panel panel-default">
<footer class="panel panel-default">
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation. This makes quite a lot of sense and completely answered my question so I've marked it as such. I also tried to upvote the very helpful answers here but I receive the following message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.".

Comment: Welcome and you're welcome, once your reputation goes a bit up you are eligible to vote :)

Comment: I was thinking about the applications of this selector but you're one step ahead and clarified it all already.

Answer (score 0):

The key piece of information in this selector is ':first', it's a jQuery selector that targets the first instance of something. So in your case, the first function is hiding all instances of any divs that have the classes 'panel' and 'default', and the second function is showing the first instance of any divs with the same classes.

```
<div class="panel panel-default"> First Instance </div> // Shown
<div class="panel panel-default"> Second Instance </div> // Hidden
<div class="panel panel-default"> Second Instance </div> //Hidden
```

Learn more here: [jQuery :first selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)